# what is `__GI_memset`? why does it cost so much CPU resource?

Tags: libc, perf, memset

I'm new to perf, and I'm trying to use it to analyse my programme.

and I got this when running perf top:

```
 PerfTop:     296 irqs/sec  kernel:62.8%  exact:  0.0% [1000Hz cycles:ppp],  (all, 6 CPUs)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    65.43%  libc-2.23.so                  [.] __GI_memset
     1.55%  libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.4.0  [.] cv::icvCvt_BGR2RGB_8u_C3R
     1.54%  libc-2.23.so                  [.] malloc
     1.32%  libc-2.23.so                  [.] _int_free
     0.92%  [kernel]                      [k] clear_page
     0.91%  libjpeg.so.8.0.2              [.] 0x000000000001b828
     0.90%  libc-2.23.so                  [.] memcpy
```

so, I just wonder what cost my 65% of CPU resource, is it really just memset in libc?
if it is, how come it cost this much?

Comment: Could just be a wrapper or alternate symbol name for `memset`? Yeah, https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/generic/symbol-hacks.h.html indicates that's likely.  It might be slow if it's the first thing that touches a new page, so it's paying page-fault costs, if your profiling it counting cycles spent in kernel mode, too.

Comment: @PeterCordes but why is memcpy just `memcpy`? And shouldn't `malloc` be the one paying for the page-fault costs?

Comment: For a large allocation, `malloc` only touches the first page to store its bookeepping info in the first 16 bytes.  Linux does lazy allocation, that's why there are page *faults* at all, instead of allocating + wiring physical pages to start with.  (It doesn't use `MAP_POPULATE`).  IDK why `memcpy` ends up shown with that symbol.  Anyway, page fault costs was just a guess, you didn't say anything about your workload or details of the situation, let alone provide a [mcve].

Comment: ok, I see the link page, may be it is just memset in assemble? I guess I might be touching some old shit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is `__GI_memset`?

It's an internal alias for `memset`.

> why does it cost so much CPU resource?

Because you call it a lot, or because you give it a lot of memory set to some value.

Judging by your next most expensive symbol `cv::icvCvt_BGR2RGB_8u_C3R`, you are doing some kind of image processing, and possibly are allocating *cleared* images.

One common mistake is to allocate a cleared image and immediately set it something else (thus wasting the time spent clearing it). But there is not enough info here to deduce whether you are doing that here.